# Building an array of verbs in J

Tags: j

Is it possible to build arrays of verbs?
I've tried this:

```
f =: >:
f2 =: f f
```

There's no syntax error but f2 is clearly not an array of verbs.
For instance

```
f2 yields f f
$ f2 yields $ f2
0 { f2 yields 0 { f2

2 3 $ f behaves in a similar way.
```

I'd also like to know if verbs can be activated by the name.

**Edited**

Instead of `f2 =: f f`, which is a composition, let's have

```
f =: >:
f2 =: 2 1 $ f

f2 yields 2 1 $ f
$ f2 yields $ f2
0 { f2 yields 0 { f2
```

It seems that `f2` represents the sequence `2 1 $ f`, while in the case of an atom, e.g. `2 1 $ 7`, the right side is a vector.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. There are many ways to combine verbs in J. `f f`, for example, is perfectly fine if you mean `f (f y)`. Can you clear up a bit what would be the desired behavior here?

Comment: It's called a jump table sometimes. A collection of various functions which are activated by index. In Python, for instance, if `f0, f1, f2` are  functions, you can build a list like `f_trio = [f0, f1, f2]` and activate the functions by indexing the list, like `f_trio[ix](7)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collection of functions is called a `gerund` in J and is formed using the tick "`":

```
g =: +`-`f
┌─┬─┬─┐
│+│-│f│
└─┴─┴─┘
```

You can use `@.` to apply the appropriate verb using its index:

```
4 2 3 (g @. 0) 1 5 6
5 7 9
4 2 3 (g @. 1) 1 5 6
3 _3 _3
4 2 3 (g @. 2) 1 5 6
1 0 0

NB. defining a 2x2 gerund:
k =: 2 2 $ +`-`*`%
┌─┬─┐
│+│-│
├─┼─┤
│*│%│
└─┴─┘

1 (((<0 0) { k) @. 0) 2
3
1 (((<0 1) { k) @. 0) 2
_1
1 (((<1 0) { k) @. 0) 2
2
1 (((<1 1) { k) @. 0) 2
0.5
```

The index can also be a new verb that depends on the arguments or a list of indices.

Comment: Thank you for your reply; it's close to what I need. I don't think it could be extended to store verbs in an n-dimensional collection, though. As another approach, the names of the verbs could be stored in arrays, providing verbs can be activated by their names in character strings. Is it possible?

Comment: J is a very different language than the "C family" of languages; I think it would be better if you directly asked for what you want to achieve so that an idiomatic J answer could be provided. **You can** create an n-dimensional collection but that feels "off".

Comment: @AttilaKaroly To add to what Eelvex has said, you can definitely say `jumpTable=: 2 1 $ f\`f` in J. If you edit your Q to include a fuller example (even in Python) on how you’d use or invoke this jump table, we can give you the J equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments point out, `f2=: f f` creates a composition and `f3=: 2 1 $ f` creates a composition as well. In the case of `f2` you are defining a hook and in the case of `f3` you are defining a fork that will take the results of `f` when it is given an argument and return the `2 1` shape of that result. The reason that it just parrots back your input is that is the way that J displays verbs without arguments. It shows you the construction, because it does not know what the verb will be applied to.

I think what you may want is the process of making a verb into a gerund, which is the noun form of a verb that can be activated in a number of ways. Creating a gerund is done by inserting a backtick between two verbs or for a single verb, a backtick between the verb and an empty string. Examples of conjunctions that work on gerunds are Agenda and Evoke Gerund.

Although this can be done in J, it is pretty clunky because J does not have the meta-operators that are necessary to manipulate verbs as if they are nouns, aside from turning them into gerunds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. All I want is an array of functions as it is easily done in Python, C#, etc., even in multi dimensional forms. Using a gerund here indeed seems to be not quite the same thing.